# Generating every number through 22 decimal places

Tags: java, math, cryptography

I want to loop through every single number from `0.0000000000000000000000` to `0.9999999999999999999999` and then perform a action on this number.

But obviously a usual for loop is using a integer and has a max value.

What's the best way to go about this in Java and do you think it would take longer than a day to get through every possible combination?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit - adding some context:

So basically I want to be able to go from a MD5 hash of a number between 0.0 -> 1.0 (with the 22 decimal places) to the plain text number. So originally I had the idea to have like a rainbow table that just maps every possible number to it's hash so I can just lookup the hash and get the corresponding number, clearly that's a bit ambitious I have realized so I need to give it a rethink - I am open to any ideas if anyone has any.

Comment: Who said that `for` loops only work with integers? While floating point precision will be an issue here, there's no reason you can't use a `double` as your counter.

Comment: Unfortunately if you are considering floating point numbers i do not think it is possible, in a reasonable amount of time, to loop through all those numbers?

Comment: so your step size `0.0000000000000000000001`?

Comment: @SabirKhan yes my step size is that

Comment: There's 10^22 numbers in that range; if you can process one every nanosecond, you should be done in 300,000 years or so.

Comment: @Arc676 I just assumed sorry, but I have just tried it out and I think the amount of decimal places I am aiming for it a problem.

Comment: even with a small number of decimal places it is going to be a lot of work... not sure of the maths maybe someone with more maths knowledge could check that? Basically as the mantissa reduces the exponent increases but to what exact magnitude i am unsure

Comment: Any chance you can process a little less numbers? As many of us have mentioned, `float`s are only so precise

Comment: Calculated using the Ruby interpreter: assuming a 2.9GHz processor and 100% processing power devoted to processing and _one cycle per number_ (so this is still very far off from the correct value) this should take 109,269.26832423775 years.

Comment: May i ask what operation you want to perform on the numbers?

Comment: @BrendanM I want to get a MD5 hash of the number and store it so eventually I can do a lookup table and so someone could give me a hash of a number and I could tell them the number. But from the sounds of things I've picked the worst way to do it so I am going to have to give it a re-think.

Comment: Ah yes interesting I think what you may be looking for is a mapping algorithm between the set of MD5 output to the range of numbers. So some computation you can run on a MD5 string that results in a number between the range you have and with good distribution. Although come to think of it one way mapping is what MD5 is tring to provide...maybe im incorrect

Comment: Little known trick: you can just multiply the number of decimal places with ~3.2 to get the number of bits. I.e. you were trying to break a 22 * 3.2 = 64 bit number. Counting to 2^64 obviously will probably take too long (unless the compiler optimizes it away of course, but that's cheating). In my head it's just times 10 divided by 3 of course.

Comment: Voted up mainly because I think the -7 vote was a bit harsh. Welcome to SO none-the-less, RootUnknown...

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be to treat your numbers as strings. That way you would be able to apply lexicographic ordering and loop through all the numbers you want. However this means that you will have to deal with 10^22 strings, where every one will be produced by the previous one. So, I am a little cautious concerining the efficiency of this. Anyway you can always refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) wikipedia link on lexicographic permutations and implement the algorithm described.

Comment: While this would be a workaround for the floating point precision thing, I don't see how this is more efficient than using `double`s. And OP wants to "perform action on this number". How would that work? Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: I think this may be too inefficient as it would have to produce as many permutations as the numbers?

Comment: I don't think doubles can handle the precision OP wants. Performing action on the numbers would require just a simple parse on this. In any case I mentioned it as a workaround. Any method will require way too much time to complete.

Comment: Using a `BigDecimal` seems like a more logical precision fix than using `String`s.

Comment: @Arc676  I want to get a MD5 hash of the number and store it so eventually I can do a lookup table and so someone could give me a hash of a number and I could tell them the number. But from the sounds of things I've picked the worst way to do it so I am going to have to give it a re-think.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with BigDecimal like the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BigDecimal end=new BigDecimal("0.9999999999999999999999");
        for(BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal("0.0000000000000000000000");
            bd.compareTo(end)<=0; 
            bd=bd.add(new BigDecimal("0.0000000000000000000001"))){
            System.out.printf("%s\n",bd.toPlainString());
        }
    }
```

It could take longer then a day, it depends on your hardware.
I hope it helps.

Comment: It could take a bit longer then a day. On my computer one loop takes about 400ns. We do 10^22 iterations here. That results in about 130mio years. I hope your computer remains intact for so long.

Comment: I don't know if the questioner has a super high distributed infrastructure to compute such values. So I only showed him how to loop over the number.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was after but now I realize what I am trying to do will take forever so I will have to approach this a different way. Appreciate it though, it will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use long numbers because there's no reason to go with doubles (they can't handle such range). long is 18-19 digits which is not enough, but you can multiply two longs by using nested loops which will give possibly best performance in java. You should use long and not Long.  Anyway as mentioned by Andy, such loop will not finish in lifetime unless you run it here

http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/219160-googles-quantum-computer-is-100-million-times-faster-than-a-conventional-system

Next only in theory, in java you can use BigDecimal numbers to write nice readable code, but it won't be the fastest. On other hand to solve lifetime problem, machine language is best to write fastest code, which would need to be clustered to many processor cores and run in parallel.

Are you trying to crack some passwords ?

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, also here is some context so basically I want to be able to go from a MD5 hash of a number between 0.0 -> 1.0 (with the 22 decimal places) to the plain text number. So originally I had the idea to have like a rainbow table that just maps every possible number to it's hash so I can just lookup the hash and get the corresponding number, clearly that's a bit ambitious I have realized so I need to give it a rethink - I am open to any ideas if anyone has any.

Comment: Well in that case you will have memory problem too. There was some effort done recently on MD5 reverse engineering and some vulnerabilities were found so MD5 is considered insecure. You might check that, but brute forcing is not the way.